# Increase Sql timeout in .net

Tags: sql, .net-services

I am gettting SQL time out error in my .net service.

As the service is already installed on the production, is there any way I can increase the timeout for the service from App.Config file.

At present, I am getting this exception after one minute, I have to make it to around 10 hours because the stored procedure we are using takes 2-2 hours to execute.

Comment: Actually those stored procedure needs to deal with many tables, I can't fight with the bussiness logic.. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timeout in your connection string with "connect Timeout = 100000000;" or whatever you want your timeout to be

Comment: Can I put connection timeout in App.Config file?

Comment: No, you can't. This will have absolutely no effect. Command Timeout in connection string is ignored.

Comment: It works for me. You put it in your connection string, which is p in app.config or web.config if you set it up through a visual studio tool

Comment: Darin is right. `Connect Timeout=1234` can be set in app.config. But that is just for *connections*. But the timeout for queries is controlled by command timeout which can *not* be set in app.config.

Comment: This is useless.  The connect timeout is different than the command timeout.  The connect timeout is only used to establish the connection, not to run queries.

Answer (score 17):

You could try setting the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) property on your [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k3z4156.aspx). I hope you are not doing this in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Darin. But for that I need to deploy the service again. Is there any way I can make changes in App.Config file so I don't need to deploy that service again?

Comment: No, there is no way doing this in app.config.

Answer (score 1):

The time out setting is up to database server.

In SQL Server Manager open the SQL Server Properties and pick the connection tab and set time out as big as You need.

Ps.

zero goes for no timeout.

Comment: Thanks Vash. But I am getting .NET exception. If I am running the same stored procedure in SQL Server Managaement studio, it is allowing me to run that for the number of hours I want.

Comment: There is a timeout on the database server and there is a separate timeout on .net.  Which ever is shorter is what will actually limit your run time.